# Tcl/sh: return elements from a nested list?

Tags: list, nested, tcl

Is there a shorthand for returning elements from a nested list?  Let's say I have a list defined as

```
%set fruits {{a apple} {b banana} {c cantaloupe} {d date}}
{a apple} {b banana} {c cantaloupe} {d date}
```

If, for example, I want to return the second value from the fourth nested set, is there a way to do this other than

```
%set myvalue [lindex [lindex $fruits 3] 1]
date
```

If I'm missing a man page, please include a link.  I can't seem to find an answer to the above in the Tcl documentation.

Comment: Since you requested a link, here's the [manual](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm). This part is relevant: "If additional index arguments are supplied, then each argument is used in turn to select an element from the previous indexing operation, allowing the script to select elements from sublists"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, here is how you can do that:

```
% lindex $fruits {3 1}
date
```

Comment: You don't even need the braces. `lindex $fruits 3 1` works just as well.